# Handling ISO 8601 date format in JSON with amcharts4

Tags: javascript, json, amcharts, p5.js

So I'm trying to read APIs and the problem I'm facing is that my JSON files have a timestamp in the ISO 8601 format 2018-08-01T00:00:00.000Z. I'm having trouble parsing the date and using it on the x-axis of the graphs I'm trying to plot. I tried using `dateAxis.baseInterval` but that didn't work either.

My JSON file looks like this:

```
{
    "current": {
        "ts": "2018-07-19T16:22:50.143Z",
        "tp": 28.1,
        "hm": 86,
        "p2": 1798.8,
        "p1": 2000,
        "co": 410
    },
    "historical": {
    "instant": [],
    "daily": [],
    "hourly": [],
    "monthly": [
        {
            "p2_sum": 24362230.400000006,
            "p2_count": 25147,
            "p1_sum": 27323591,
            "p1_count": 25147,
            "p01_sum": 0,
            "p01_count": 25147,
            "co_sum": 10377809,
            "co_count": 25147,
            "hm_sum": 1990387,
            "hm_count": 25147,
            "tp_sum": 751444.6000000008,
            "tp_count": 25147,
            "voc_sum": 0,
            "voc_count": 25147,
            "ts": "2018-07-01T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "p2_sum": 18671220.4,
            "p2_count": 30570,
            "p1_sum": 21348609,
            "p1_count": 30570,
            "p01_sum": 0,
            "p01_count": 30570,
            "co_sum": 12710586,
            "co_count": 30570,
            "hm_sum": 2378769,
            "hm_count": 30570,
            "tp_sum": 940682.1999999995,
            "tp_count": 30570,
            "voc_sum": 0,
            "voc_count": 30570,
            "ts": "2018-06-01T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "p2_sum": 43528318.00000001,
            "p2_count": 39021,
            "p1_sum": 48835953,
            "p1_count": 39021,
            "p01_sum": 0,
            "p01_count": 39021,
            "co_sum": 16396448,
            "co_count": 39021,
            "hm_sum": 2519117,
            "hm_count": 39021,
            "tp_sum": 1242705.2999999986,
            "tp_count": 39021,
            "voc_sum": 0,
            "voc_count": 39021,
            "ts": "2018-05-01T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "p2_sum": 13674871.200000005,
            "p2_count": 40870,
            "p1_sum": 17433589,
            "p1_count": 40870,
            "p01_sum": 0,
            "p01_count": 40870,
            "co_sum": 17394057,
            "co_count": 40870,
            "hm_sum": 2662629,
            "hm_count": 40870,
            "tp_sum": 1218448.0999999999,
            "tp_count": 40870,
            "voc_sum": 0,
            "voc_count": 40870,
            "ts": "2018-04-01T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "p2_sum": 1161646.1,
            "p2_count": 24718,
            "p1_sum": 1587661,
            "p1_count": 24718,
            "p01_sum": 0,
            "p01_count": 24718,
            "co_sum": 10479045,
            "co_count": 24718,
            "hm_sum": 1495412,
            "hm_count": 24718,
            "tp_sum": 681216.3361000005,
            "tp_count": 24718,
            "voc_sum": 0,
            "voc_count": 24718,
            "ts": "2018-03-01T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "p2_sum": 541102.4999999994,
            "p2_count": 5435,
            "p1_sum": 770352,
            "p1_count": 5435,
            "p01_sum": 0,
            "p01_count": 5435,
            "co_sum": 2363708,
            "co_count": 5435,
            "hm_sum": 329164,
            "hm_count": 5435,
            "tp_sum": 134607.03550000003,
            "tp_count": 5435,
            "voc_sum": 0,
            "voc_count": 5435,
            "ts": "2018-02-01T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "p2_sum": 752770.7999999999,
            "p2_count": 4256,
            "p1_sum": 1078140,
            "p1_count": 4256,
            "p01_sum": 0,
            "p01_count": 4256,
            "co_sum": 2057621,
            "co_count": 4256,
            "hm_sum": 233433,
            "hm_count": 4256,
            "tp_sum": 97060.19720000004,
            "tp_count": 4256,
            "voc_sum": 0,
            "voc_count": 4256,
            "ts": "2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
        }
    ]
},
"settings": {
    "node_name": "orangi town"
}
}
```

And this is my html and JS code. I'm using the p5.js library for reading the JSON files (read the APIs from a URL) and im using amcharts4 for the graphs.

```js
function setup() {
 loadJSON("assets/JSON/data.JSON", fnc)
}

function fnc(data) {
 am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

 var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

 chart.data = data.historical.daily;

 chart.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = "i";

 var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());

 var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

 var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
 series.dataFields.dateX = "ts";
 series.dataFields.valueY = "p1_count";
 series.tooltipText = "{valueY.value}"

 dateAxis.baseInterval = {
  "timeUnit": "day",
  "count": 1
 }

 chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>simple-column-chart</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo+Narrow" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/p5.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chartdiv"></div>
    <script src="../../../core.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../charts.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../themes/animated.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if the chart requires the date in some other format (check the docs, if you haven't already), then the ISO string should be parseable by JS Date and then you can output it in a different format again.

Comment: Looks like there's a couple of bugs at the moment. You'll need to sort your data into date ascending order for now, despite our docs saying otherwise, to make your chart display properly. If you want to render your axis in descending order, you can set the axis' renderer to invert the order, e.g. `dateAxis.renderer.inversed = true`. There's also a parsing issue with using `inputDateFormat = "i"` that our devs are currently looking into which is giving off by one dates on my end. Since it's only daily data, you can set `inputDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"` instead to get the desired results.

Comment: What format do your dates need to be in? How have you tried converting the dates? Can you please post a [mcve] of just the part that converts from one format to another?

Comment: @xorspark sorting the data in ascending order worked and the graph is getting displayed as expected! I have another question though, you might have noticed I'm using the p5.js library to load my JSON file. I wanted to use the amcharts 4 inbuilt `.dataSource` object to be able to make a live graph but I can't figure out how to access the nested JSON objects. Is a nested JSON file not fully supported yet?

Comment: @SananbinTahir No, nested JSON is not supported. You need to flatten it or use the `parseended` event to manipulte the data and set the array directly. See [here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/data/loading-external-data/).

Comment: @SananbinTahir we also just released beta.41 which fixes the parsing problem with `"i"` in `inputDateFormat`. Make sure you clear your browser cache if you're linking to our files directly or download the latest files from github.